# dplyr to check each firm has June history

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a 1m+ data set and need to go through and check that for each firm(`cusip`) and year(`fyear`) there is an observation for June, where `datadate` is YYYYMMDD.  I've tried using `substr()` to pull out the month and did a logical test and if true then leave alone, but if not, that `cusip` gets removed.  However, this is not working and is returning errors about not a logical argument and condition lengths.  I've stepped through each of these outside of `dplyr` to make sure everything is working and I haven't run into any problems except for inside `dplyr`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Reproducible code :

```
tdata <- structure(list(cusip = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2), fyear = c(1962L, 
1963L, 1964L, 1965L, 1966L, 1967L, 1968L, 1969L, 1970L, 1971L, 
1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1962L, 1963L, 1964L, 1965L, 
1966L, 1967L, 1969L), datadate = c(19620631L, 19630631L, 19640631L, 
19651231L, 19661231L, 19670631L, 19680631L, 19691231L, 19700631L, 
19710631L, 19720631L, 19730631L, 19740631L, 19751231L, 19760631L, 
19770631L, 19780631L, 19791231L, 19800631L, 19810631L, 19820631L, 
19831231L, 19841231L, 19850631L, 19621231L, 19630631L, 19640631L, 
19650631L, 19660631L, 19670631L, 19690631L)), .Names = c("cusip", "fyear", 
"datadate"), row.names = c(NA, 31L), class = "data.frame")

tdata %>% 
  group_by(cusip) %>% 
  group_by(fyear) %>% 
  arrange(desc(datadate)) %>% 
  if(substr(datadate[1], 5,6) != 06) cusip <- NULL
```

Error :

```
Error in if (.) as.numeric(substr(datadate[1], 5, 6)) != 6 else cusip <- NULL : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) as.numeric(substr(datadate[1], 5, 6)) != 6 else cusip <- NULL :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a column for month first?  Something like:

```
library(dplyr)
tdata$month <- substr(tdata$datadate, 5, 6)

tdata %>%
  group_by(cusip, fyear) %>%
  mutate(has_June = month == "06")
```

Notice that month is a string, therefore to check for equality you will need to use quotes.

All in one go:

```
tdata %>%
  group_by(cusip, fyear) %>%
  mutate(month = substr(datadate, 5, 6),
         has_June = month == "06")
```

Then you could find those without June with the addition of: `%>% filter(month != "06")`

Comment: Actually, this is applying a logic that if it has June as a month it's true, otherwise false.  I need it to check if each year has a June data set and if so, keep all months for that year.  Otherwise, drop that cusip code for that year.

Comment: then change it to `has_June = any(month == "06")`